# Is there a way in phpunit to use the database extension together with the selenium extension?

Tags: database, unit-testing, phpunit, selenium-rc

Basically, I want to run selenium tests that allow the database to be setup to a define status before each Selenium test. How would I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have written my own database setup and teardown routines which I added to a child of selenium testcase

Answer (score 0):

Given that Selenium just calls url's you could simply use the setUp() and tearDown() methods to get your database into a specific state. [Transaction rollback](http://xunitpatterns.com/Transaction%20Rollback%20Teardown.html) is one approach to keeping the database consistent.

Then call url's mapping into the project under test (and your test database) e.g.:

```
$this->open('http://testing.example.org/system/under/test.php');
```